# Killer-sequence для Quick Sort

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Имеется код для Quick-Sort, представленный ниже. Здесь пивотом будет являться серединный элемент. А как построить пример, при котором данная сортировка будет работать за O(n^2)? Нашёл лишь статью http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf, но не разобрался, так как плохо владею английским. Можно ли ещё прикрепить пример кода, который будет генерировать killer-sequence за O(n)?

```
void qsort(int *a,int l,int r)
   {
   if(l>=r)
   return;
    int x = a[(l+r)/2];
    int i = l,j = r;
    while(i<=j){
            while(a[i] < x) ++i;
        while(a[j] > x) --j;
        if(i<=j){
            swap(a[i],a[j]);
            ++i,--j;
        }
    }
    qsort(a,l,j);
    qsort(a,i,r);
}
```

Comment: Какой же мерзкий квиксорт. Мало того, что партишн вшит в самую функцию, из-за чего код представляет собой жуткое месево, так еще и рекурсия не преобразована в цикл и не используется стек.

Comment: @typemoon: Ну, это очень низкоуровневая имплементация. Вот вам чистое решение на Хаскеле: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7717691/276994

Comment: Протестить бы это решение на последовательности из хотя бы 100 000 элементов=) Надо очень хорошо знать хаскель и правильно использовать ленивость, чтобы алгоритмы на нем не тормозили. Слишком чувствительный язык к непониманию его основных идей. Есть мнение, что программисты не знают даже 10% хаскеля, это профессорская тема, а программисты знают только какой-то минимум, которого хватит только на несуществующую должность хаскель-джуниора.

Comment: @typemoon: Зато чтобы понять суть алгоритма и убедиться в отсутствии багов самое оно. Вон Кнут как-то писал, что практически все знакомые ему программисты при реализации тривиального двоичного поиска допускали ошибки с индексами +/-1 с первого раза.

Comment: По-моему единственная здравая оценка программиста - может или нет он сделать проект в срок, может или нет зарабатывать деньги, а не словоблудие уровня хабра. А тонкости алгоритмов сложнее бинарного поиска забываются, потому что основное свойство памяти - забывание. Об алгоритмах достаточно знать, на каких данных они лучше всего работают, достоинства и  недостатки, сложность основных операций на структуре данных и все такое. Сейчас не 70-е годы, и поэтому за рубежом на младших курсах изучают фреймворки и технологии.

Comment: @typemoon С этим согласен на 99.9%. В оставшийся 0.1% входят как раз таки тонкости работы тех или иных алгоритмов. Верно, что "Об алгоритмах достаточно знать, на каких данных они лучше всего работают, достоинства и недостатки, сложность основных операций на структуре данных и все такое". Но если знать лучший случай, то почему бы не найти худший, хотя бы ради интереса?

Comment: У меня был очень плохой случай, когда в очень длинной возрастающей последовательности достаточно часто вставлялись маленькие числа, так что они были как впадины в этой последовательности.

Comment: @typemoon Скажу, что похожая картина будет наблюдаться и здесь. В ссылке выше даже есть картинка для худшего случая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эх, тряхнём стариной :) Давайте-ка протрассируем индексы назад. Получается вот что:

```
void prepare_killer(int* a, int length)
{
    int origidx[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        origidx[i] = i;

    // эмулируем прохождение qsort по плохому пути
    // r будет всё время константой
    int r = length - 1;

    // а l будет каждый раз увеличиваться на 1
    for (int l = 0; l < r; l++)
    {
        // так будет выбран pivot:
        int p = (l + r) / 2;

        // элементы с индексами l и p поменяются местами
        swap(origidx[l], origidx[p]);
    }

    // имея позиции, куда придут данные, можно теперь их расставить:
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        a[origidx[i]] = i + 1;
}
```

Для проверки напишем модифицированную версию `qsort`, которая будет проверять, что данные отправляют её всё время по «плохому» пути: одно из двух подзаданий будет всегда пустым.

```
bool qsort_check_failed = false;

void qsort_with_check(int *a, int l, int r)
{
    if (l >= r)
        return;
    int x = a[(l + r) / 2];
    int i = l, j = r;
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (a[i] < x) ++i;
        while (a[j] > x) --j;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
            ++i, --j;
        }
    }

    if (!(l >= j))
    {
        cout << "Mistake: have non-empty first subtask!" << endl;
        qsort_check_failed = true;
    }
    qsort_with_check(a, l, j);
    qsort_with_check(a, i, r);
}
```

Проверка здесь: http://ideone.com/a9L22p

Comment: Полное и понятное объяснение. Спасибо.

Comment: @Ильдар: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение твоей задачи, это уже отсортированный массив. В этом случае у тебя quick sort будет давать худший результат.

```
int * array = new int[7];
for(int size = 0; size < 7; size++)
{
   (*array)[size] = size;
}
```

Это как вариант заполнения

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь не достигается глубина рекурсии, равная n-1.

Comment: А зачем тебе глубина рекурсии?  Тебе ведь нужно что бы сортировка имела худший временной результат. Или есть какое-то ещё условие?

Comment: Цитата из википедии: "Выбор среднего элемента. Устраняет деградацию для предварительно отсортированных данных, но оставляет возможность случайного появления или намеренного подбора «плохого» массива." Предложенный вами случай не является наихудшим, так как даже нет ни одной операции swap.

Comment: Тогда возможен такой вариант массива [6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: При первой итерации выберется 1 - это худший случай. На второй выберется 3 при первом вызове и 3 во втором. Тогда это не будет худшим случаем хотя бы потому, что пивот примерно посередине. Ну и последующие итерации будут работать нормально.

Comment: @typemoon Какой heapsort?

Comment: Сортировка пирамидой, не имеет худшего случая, работает всегда ровно за O(nlogn)

Comment: @typemoon А вы можете доказать, что он в лучшем случае работает за O(nlogn)?

Comment: Уже доказано в книге Кормена. Логарифм появляется из-за высоты дерева.

Comment: Кстати, наверно, лучший случай будет когда последовательность убывающая. Тогда каждый элемент ставится сразу на свое место без перестроения кучи. То есть первый на вершину, следующие два - на уровень ниже и т.д.